# Why is not detecting the Get method?

Tags: java, android, methods, get

```
   import android.content.*;
   import android.database.*;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
   import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
   import android.util.Log;

   public class DBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



private static final int DATA_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
public static final String TABLE = "table";
public static final String COLUMN_CONDUCTIVITY ="Conductivity";
public static final String COLUMN_OXYGEN = "Oxygen";
public static final String COLUMN_PH = "pH";
public static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "username";
public static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password";
public static final String COLUMN_MOISTURE = "moisture";

public DBAdapter(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATA_VERSION);
}

public DBAdapter(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    super(context, name, factory, version, errorHandler);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String query = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE + "(" +
            COLUMN_CONDUCTIVITY+ " FLOAT" +
            COLUMN_OXYGEN+ " INTEGER" +
            COLUMN_PH+ "FLOAT " +
            COLUMN_USERNAME+ "STRING PRIMARY KEY " +
            COLUMN_PASSWORD + "TEXT" +
            COLUMN_MOISTURE+ " INTEGER "+
            ");";

    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP_TABLE_IF_EXITS" + TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}
//Add a new row to the database
public void addData(DBAdapter data){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_CONDUCTIVITY, data.getConductivity

    values.put(COLUMN_OXYGEN, data.getOxygen());
    values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, data.getPassword());
    values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, data.getUsername());
    values.put(COLUMN_PH, data.getPh());

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();
}
//Delete data

public void deleteData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST, TABLE");
}
public String databaseToString(){

    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM" + TABLE + "WHERE 1";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Conductivity"))!= null){
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(("Conductivity")));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
    }
    db.close();
    return dbString;

}
```

}

My code above is not detecting the get methods from the code below, and yes they are in the same project. Any of the getters can be found.

Anyone could helpme please?

Please I am trying this SQLite database to work.

```
public class DatabaseList {



    private String username;
    private String password;
    private float conductivity;
    private float pH;
    private int oxygen;
    private String date;

    public DatabaseList(){}

    public DatabaseList(String username, String password, String date, int oxygen, float pH, float conductivity){
        this.conductivity = conductivity;
        this.date = date;
        this.oxygen = oxygen;
        this.password = password;
        this.pH = pH;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public float getConductivity() {
        return conductivity;
    }

    public void setConductivity(float conductivity) {
        this.conductivity = conductivity;
    }

    public float getpH() {
        return pH;
    }

    public void setpH(float pH) {
        this.pH = pH;
    }

    public int getOxygen() {
        return oxygen;
    }

    public void setOxygen(int oxygen) {
        this.oxygen = oxygen;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have this `DBAdapter data` while you need `DatabaseList ` to access getter and setter

Answer (score 1):

Well, the DBAdapter class  and the Database list are not even the same class type, 
Has the DBAdapter class a

```
getOxygen ()
```

method? I don't think so... 
So that is the error
You are trying to call undefined methods in another class..